# Specifiy version of R to run when running a script from bash

Tags: r, bash, rscript

I am trying to run an R script from a bash script using the `Rscript` command. The cluster I am on has multiple versions of R, and is telling me: "Error: This is R version 2.15.1. Package 'raster' requires >= 3.0.0. Is there a way to specify the version of R to run `Rscript` with?

```
#!/bin/sh
Rscript Test.R
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use a full path, then it will run the version that is found first in your $PATH variable.  The solution is to either have your path have the R directory at the beginning, or to the correct path (e.g. 'alias R=/opt/my/path/R') and run the script with `shopt -s expand_aliases'

Comment: ended up just running it from the full path. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeJewski you tagged this bash, but you are running /bin/sh.  shopt is a bash command.  I didn't notice you are using a different shell than what you tagged.

Comment: I realized that after, even after putting /bin/bash, I wasn't able to get it to work. This was ultimately because I was submitting this to a cluster using the qsub command, and had to manual set it to run it using qsub -S /bin/bash. Both ways ended up working!